# 3d Card Flip animation takes too long

Tags: jquery, html, css, css-animations

I have a 3d Card Flip animation on click but it takes too long to trigger and I don't know why.

See example here (Scroll down and click on any B&W picture)

http://www.grancomunicaciones.com/nueva/

here's my code:

THE CSS

```
.flip-container {
-webkit-perspective: 1000;
            -moz-perspective: 1000;
            perspective: 1000;

            border: 0px solid #ccc;
        }


            .flip-container:hover .flipper, .flip-container.hover .flipper, #flip-toggle.flip .flipper {
                -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
                -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg);
                transform: rotateY(180deg);
                filter: FlipH;
                -ms-filter: "FlipH";
            }

        .flip-container, .front, .back {
            width: 320px;
            height: 427px;
        }

        .flipper {
            -webkit-transition: 0.6s;
            -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;

            -moz-transition: 0.6s;
            -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;

            transition: 0.6s;
            transform-style: preserve-3d;

            position: relative;
        }

        .front, .back {
            -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
            -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
            backface-visibility: hidden;

            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
        }

        .front {
            background: lightgreen;
            z-index: 2;
        }

        .back {
            -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
            -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg);
            transform: rotateY(180deg);
        }

        .front .name {
            font-size: 2em;
            display: inline-block;
            background: rgba(33, 33, 33, 0.9);
            color: #f8f8f8;
            font-family: Courier;
            padding: 5px 10px;
            border-radius: 5px;
            bottom: 60px;
            left: 25%;
            position: absolute;
            text-shadow: 0.1em 0.1em 0.05em #333;

            -webkit-transform: rotate(-20deg);
            -moz-transform: rotate(-20deg);
            transform: rotate(-20deg);
        }

        .back-logo {
            position: absolute;
            top: 40px;
            left: 90px;
            width: 160px;
            height: 117px;
            background: url(logo.png) 0 0 no-repeat;
        }

        .back-title {
            font-weight: bold;
            color: #00304a;
            position: absolute;
            top: 180px;
            left: 0;
            right: 0;
            text-align: center;
            text-shadow: 0.1em 0.1em 0.05em #acd7e5;
            font-family: Courier;
            font-size: 2em;
        }

        .back p {
            position: absolute;
            bottom: 40px;
            left: 0;
            right: 0;
            text-align: center;
            padding: 0 20px;
        }

        /* vertical */
        .vertical.flip-container {
            position: relative;
        }

            .vertical .back {
                -webkit-transform: rotateX(180deg);
                -moz-transform: rotateX(180deg);
                transform: rotateX(180deg);
            }

            .vertical.flip-container .flipper {
                -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 213.5px;
                -moz-transform-origin: 100% 213.5px;
                transform-origin: 100% 213.5px;
            }

            .vertical.flip-container:hover .flipper {
                -webkit-transform: rotateX(-180deg);
                -moz-transform: rotateX(-180deg);
                transform: rotateX(-180deg);
            }
    body {
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}
```

THE JS

```
function rotate(id) {
    $("#behind").load("person.php?id="+id,function(){
    document.querySelector('#flip-toggle').classList.toggle('flip');
    });
}
```

THE HTML

```
<div class="flip-container" id="flip-toggle">
    <div class="flipper"> 
        <div class="front" id="front" style="background: url(imagenes/fotos.jpg); background-size:100%; overflow:hidden">
            Front content
        </div> 
        <div class="back" id="atras">
            Back content
        </div> 
    </div> 
</div> 
<div id="bot1" style="visibility:visible; position:relative; z-index:5; cursor:pointer; float:left;" onClick="rotate('1');"></div>
```

Maybe there's an easier way? I need the actual 3D rotation instead of polifill wich only simulates it (I need the content to be viewable during the animation).

Your help is greatly appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You're calling the toggle function on load complete, which could give you a delay.

Since you don't have too many 'back card' elements, I suggest you preload them and avoid the delay completely.

Comment: Correction, I see the animation, but it takes *way* too long. :)

Answer (score 0):

You're loading up an entire page, including all of it's assets (javascript and CSS) when all you want it just a bit of HTML.

The animation itself does not take long, what takes long is the request to `person.php` (it took about 1.7s on my browser for person.php to load along with all of its assets)

As an aside, why are you using `jQuery` and `document.querySelector` together? That kind of defeats the purpose of using `jQuery` to being with.

Chances are all you want to load is the HTML and not all the assets. It will be much faster (about 10x is my guess) if you can remove the assets from person.php

Comment: Thank you Shomz and Adam.  I'm using document.querySelector from the tutorial I found on the effect (which is from where I took the code and changed it). Adam I followed your advice and indeed it loads so much faster! Also I will follow Shomz's advice to preload the flip elements to make it even faster, thank you!

Comment: `querySelector` has nothing to do with why it's slow - I just made a point of mentioning it because `jQuery` essentially replaces `querySelector` and makes it cross-browser compliant. Ignore that part for the time being, the reason why the effect is slow is because the AJAX is slow.